# Can all related contacts be notified about upcoming membership renewals?

Tags: civicontribute, civimail, civimember

We have an uncommon relationship between association managers and my client's member organizations. Since there may be multiple contacts in an association management firm and there may be significant turnover, my client wants to send membership renewal information, including invoices to all the related contacts for each organization (all the members are organizational entities).

Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this? In most cases, the only contacts we have on file are the association managers, instead of a central email for the association.

Answer (score 1):

There's a feature I wrote for Email API for use with CiviRules called "send email to a related contact".  I haven't looked at it recently to see if you can specify "any relationship" as opposed to a specific one, but it should get you most of the way to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if the related contacts all are 'current employee' and are 'permissioned' then they can all effectively use the 'on behalf of' feature to do the renewal. That doesn't answer your question about how to notify them - but i think it is a requirement for them then be able to perform the renewal.

The next step I think would be to have them all 'inherit' the membership, which is a setting in the Membership Types

The final step (which I am not certain about) would be to see if you can set up a Scheduled Reminder based on Memberships and have it be sent to those who have inherited it. That assumes that this is a Rolling membership cycle.

If you membership is static then you could presumably achieve that last step just by setting up a group of all with 'inherited memberships' and send out a Mailing with the renewal link in it.

Comment: Logically, I had reached this conclusion. My question goes to the issue of notifications, since we don't know who the active contact will be at renewal time because of staff turnover, can we issue the renewal notices and invoices so that all the staff see the invoices? For clarity, the constituents are pension funds and they are very invoice oriented.

Comment: If Scheduled Reminders cannot be set to select 'inherited memberships' then you could look in to CiviRules perhaps

Comment: I'll  look at those options. Thanks for the heads up.